# Зачем требуется указывать имя базового класса при обращении к наследуемой функции, если существует только один вариант разрешения этого обращения?

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++, language-lawyer

Что конкретно в данном случае мешает обращаться к функции базового класса напрямую по имени без указания класса? Если `protected` запрещает любое другое обращение к `a_func()` кроме как через `A<​T​>` из класса унаследованного от `A<​T​>`, то какая неоднозначность (потенциально) могла бы возникнуть, если не указывать `A<​T​>` при обращении к `a_func()`?

```
template<typename T>
struct A {
protected:
    static int a_func() { return 42; }
};

template<typename T>
struct B : A<T> {
//  static int b_func() { return a_func(); }       // Почему это не компилируется?
    static int b_func() { return A<T>::a_func(); } // Зачем требуется указывать A<T>?
};

int main() {
    std::cout << B<void>::b_func() << std::endl;
}
```

Если раскомментировать первый вариант b_func(), то GCC 4.9.2 ругается следующим образом:

```
error: there are no arguments to ‘a_func’ that depend on a template parameter,
so a declaration of ‘a_func’ must be available [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Кстати, VC++ 2015 вполне разрешает...

Comment: @Harry, а потом получаем различные результаты для одинакового кода: [vc++](http://rextester.com/YUEMU39665), [g++](http://rextester.com/FBYN28857)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Это пример так называемого двухфазного поиска имён (two-stage name lookup). G++ реализует его начиная с версии 3.4. Его особенность заключается в том, что поиск делится на два этапа: для всех имён, не зависящих от аргумента шаблона, поиск осуществляется на этапе разбора шаблона, для зависимых имён - при инстанциировании шаблона. Это способствует выявлению ошибок на более раннем этапе, т.е. не дожидаясь инстанциирования шаблона.

Из [стандарта](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf#section.14.6):

> When looking for the declaration of a name used in a template
>   definition, the usual lookup rules (3.4.1,
>   3.4.2) are used for non-dependent names. The lookup of names dependent on the template parameters is postponed until the actual template
>   argument is known (14.6.2)

В коде

```
static int b_func() { return a_func(); }
```

функции `b_func()` и `a_func()` не используются в зависимом контексте (то есть не зависят от типа аргумента шаблона), поэтому компилятор будет искать в окружающем пространстве имён (в данном случае это глобальное пространство). Поиск имени в базовой структуре не будет осуществляться, поскольку он является зависимым.

Для разрешения этой проблемы можно использовать функцию `a_func()` в зависимом контексте, например, используя ключевое слово `this` (в статическом контексте не подходит), либо используя `A<T>::` или `using A<T>::a_func();`.

Некоторые компиляторы будут компилировать данный пример без ошибок, поскольку не реализуют двухфазный поиск имён.

Подробнее: [12.7.2 Name Lookup, Templates, and Accessing Members of Base Classes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Name-lookup.html)

Comment: `this` в случае ТС не подойдет, ибо `static` функция. Ещё было бы неплохо сносок на пункты Стандарта.

Comment: @alexolut, спасибо, не обратил внимание - поправил. По поводу стандарта - не знаток по этой части, попробую поискать.